# "admitted to having spent" or "admitted to spending"

Tags: gerunds

1. Jack finally admitted to having spent it all.
2. Jack finally admitted to spending it all.

In the second sentence ***having*** has been omitted. Do they mean same? If not, please tell me the differences between them.

Comment: "Admit" is followed by gerund. So it is not possible to write "admit to have spent" or the other alternative that you have written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"admitted to having spent" and "admitted to spending" mean the same. "Admitted to having spent" is correct and exact use of the past perfect gerund, but in colloquial language this is often simplified and the gerund of present tense is used instead.

Answer (score 1):

**admit to** wants a nominal complement:

admitted to {*having* spent} it all

admitted to {*spending*} it all

admitted to the deed

admitted to the crime

admitted to the robbery, the theft, etc

With **having**, we need the past participle, *spent*.

Comment: Actually I don't what the differences between their meanings. I would to know what they individual mean.

Comment: There is no *practical* difference. The only difference would be the possible (faint) nuance that **having spent** refers to the action as one which has run to completion, and **spending** refers to an action in progress.  In either case, "all" conveys the idea of completion.